# CardView doesn't work properly

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-6.0-marshmallow, cardview

I have a work with the RecyclerView, and I use the CardView as well.I have made all these standards procedures (created the ViewHolder, implemented necessary methods) but the problem is that CardView's corners aren't rounded.I get only rectangular corners of the CardView.

Here is the XML code of Adapter's "main layout":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="10dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="30dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/adapterText"
            android:text="@string/textCaption"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/adapterDate"
            android:text="@string/date"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/adapterText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

And another layout with RecyclerView:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/contactList"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And initialization of the  RecyclerView:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View root, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (root != null) {
        RecyclerView mRecyclerContactList=(RecyclerView)(root.findViewById(R.id.contactList));
        mContactAdapter=new ContactAdapter(getContext(),mContextualMultiMode,mContactList);
        mRecyclerContactList.setAdapter(mContactAdapter);
        RecyclerView.ItemAnimator animator=new DefaultItemAnimator();
        mRecycle

rContactList.setItemAnimator(animator);
            RecyclerView.ItemDecoration mVerticalDecoration=new DividerItemDecoration
                    (getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
            mRecyclerContactList.addItemDecoration(mVerticalDecoration);
            mRecyclerContactList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

        }

    }
```

Does anybody know how to solve this issue?

Comment: What version of Android are you testing this on?

Comment: I use Nougat, 7.0

Comment: Is it a horizontal Recyclerview? Could you post your entire layout xml?

Comment: Perhaps it has to do with your item decoration? Try removing that to see if that is the problem.

Comment: I've tried it before, but it does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cardview as root causes strange problems to me. Try to use Relativelayout as root.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what was.

Comment: So does LinearLayout. Using them as root can cause weired problems.

Answer (score 0):

Hi try using this code

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:cardview="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    cardview:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
    cardview:cardElevation="6dp"
    cardview:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
    cardview:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    cardview:contentPadding="0dp">
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: It still doesn't work.Have you ever had the same problem?It works fine when the CardView isn't a root element, but that is not what do I want.

Answer (score 0):

> Use this code when you are using cardview

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cardview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:elevation="100dp"
            card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/cardview_initial_background"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_large"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_large"
            >
```